# Creating a jQuery plugin with getJSON inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asynchronous

I am not sure if this is due to the fact that `getJSON` is asynchronous or not. I think that would be the most obvious reason, but I don't have a clear understanding of how that works. In my js file, I call the `healthCheck` method on the body element. Nothing happens. Is my `getJSON` callback function even getting called? I don't know.

I have uploaded the script on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeu3znfx/).

The code is also below:

```
var baseURL = "http://someURL";
var id = "00000001";
var key = "0000aaaa-aa00-00a0-a00a-0000000a0000";
var healthcheck = "/version/healthcheck?";

( function($) {
        $.fn.healthCheck = function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().toJSON().toString();
            var request = healthcheck + "timestamp=" + timestamp + "&devid=" + id;
            var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(request, key);
            request = baseURL + request + "&signature=" + signature;
            $.getJSON(request, function(data) {
                var result = new Object();
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    result.key = val;
                    if (val == false) {
                        this.innerHTML = "PTV API is currently not working. Error type: " + key + ".";
                    } else {
                        this.append(key + " working. <br />");
                    }
                });
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

Many thanks in advance. I hope my query is well placed. If anyone knows some good resources to get a better understanding of asynchronous methods in jQuery that would be greatly appreciated, also. I haven't found many that have been easy to follow yet.

Comment: Why create `result` if you are not going to use it for anything? Also, JSON is already a string; you do not have to call `.toString()` on it. Putting the variables at the top inside the anonymous function would probably be a good idea, as well (some other script may change the values inadvertently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 1) setting `context` of [jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) to `this` of `$.fn.healthCheck` ; 2) create reference to `this` object at `$.each()`

```
var baseURL = "http://someURL";
var id = "00000001";
var key = "0000aaaa-aa00-00a0-a00a-0000000a0000";
var healthcheck = "/version/healthcheck?";

(function($) {
        $.fn.healthCheck = function() {
            // set `this` object within  `$.getJSON`
            var timestamp = new Date().toJSON().toString();
            var request = healthcheck + "timestamp=" + timestamp + "&devid=" + id;
            var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(request, key);
            request = baseURL + request + "&signature=" + signature;
            $.ajax({
              url:request
            , type:"GET"
            , contentType: false
            , context: this
            , processData:false
            }).then(function(data) {
                // reference to `this` within `$.each()`
                var that = this; 
                var result = new Object();
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, val) {
                    result.key = val;
                    if (val == false) {
                        // `that` : `this`
                        that.innerHTML = "PTV API is currently not working. Error type: " + key + ".";
                    } else {
                        that.append(key + " working. <br />");
                        console.log("complete"); // notification
                    }
                });
            }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); // log errors
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));

$("body").healthCheck();
```

See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323?s=3|0.0000#14220323)

```js
var baseURL = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/raw/62775b7420f8df6b3d83244270d26495e40a1e9d/a.json";
var id = "00000001";
var key = "0000aaaa-aa00-00a0-a00a-0000000a0000";
var healthcheck = "/version/healthcheck?";

(function($) {
        $.fn.healthCheck = function() {
            var timestamp = new Date().toJSON().toString();
            var request = healthcheck + "timestamp=" + timestamp + "&devid=" + id;
            var signature = 123;// CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(request, key);
            request = baseURL + request + "&signature=" + signature;
            $.ajax({
              url:request
            , type:"GET"
            , contentType: false
            , context: this
            , processData:false
            }).then(function(data) {
                var that = this;
                var result = new Object();
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, val) {
                    result.key = val;
                    if (val == false) {
                        that.innerHTML = "PTV API is currently not working. Error type: " + key + ".";
                    } else {
                        that.append(key + " working. <br />");
                        console.log("complete"); // notification
                    }
                });
            }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); // log errors
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));

$("body").healthCheck()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain why I need the line `var that = this;`? It only worked after I changed those lines.

Comment: `this` inside of `$.each()` would refer to `data` object , not an DOM element where `.innerHTML` , `.append()` are called.